# Getting 'nan' when inserting method in stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, nan

I have simplifed some methods for ease of understanding and correction of the error.  I get a 'nan' instead of getting the number and don't understand why. I want to put the getNumber method inside the return statement.  When I have the method inside it returns a string of nan but when I just put the 26 inside it returns 26, what I want.

```
-(double) getNumber { return 26; }


-(NSString *) convertToString {
        return [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%Lf",[self getNumber]];
// returns 'nan'           when I replace [self getNumber] with 15 I get 15
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use "%f" instead of "%Lf", since you are passing a `double`, not a `long double`

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to long double, because thats what I am using everywhere else, nice catch

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple problems in your code.

1. Return a double, not an integer in `getNumber`. While automatic coercion will occur, write clean code.
2. Use the `%g` format specifier, not `%Lf`. `%g` is for doubles.

Comment: I thought that %Lf was for long doubles, and %f for doubles. Is is not accurate?

Comment: That is indeed not accurate. `%f` is for 32-bit `float` numbers. Also, you do not have a long double, you have a double. For that, you use `%g`.

Comment: You can use either e,f or g to format doubles. They have slightly different conventions for whether (and when) exponential notation is used. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

Comment: `float` is promoted to `double` in a variadic argument list, so `%f` and `%g` will both work with either type.

Comment: @jer: both %f and %g operate on doubles and floats. %g just uses either %f or %e format, whichever uses less space.

Comment: @michaellindahl: You are correct, %Lf is for long doubles and %f is for doubles, but you are returning a double (not a long double) and you are using %Lf which is why your format fails.

Answer (score 0):

It's your format specifier. You should use "%g" to format a double.